# coordinates inside a canvas on android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm development an app for drawing lines between two points. For example:

I have a map like this (Please imagine The X are dots):

```
   X     X     X     X     X     X     X     X     X     X
```

Each one have been created with this sentence:

> canvas.drawCircle(50, 100, 15, paint);
>         canvas.drawCircle(148, 100, 15, paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(246, 100, 15, paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(344,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(442,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(540,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(638,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(736,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(834,100,15,paint);
>           canvas.drawCircle(932,100,15,paint);

And I use a listener for catch the position of user interaction

> case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
>   downx = event.getX(); 
>   downy = event.getY();

The problem is when I make clic between the points (932,100) and (832,100) the X position return 771 and it is not a value between 832 and 932.

This is my code:

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    int PMaxX=0;
    int PMaxY =0;
    final ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Matriz = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
        display.getSize(size);
        PMaxX = size.x;
        PMaxY = size.y;
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
       // Log.d("State", "Prueba menor 13");
        PMaxX  = display.getWidth();
        PMaxY = display.getHeight();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(PMaxX, PMaxY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 100, 15, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(148, 100, 15, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(246, 100, 15, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(344,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(442,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(540,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(638,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(736,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(834,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(932,100,15,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(1065,100,15,paint);


    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    drawingImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    downx = event.getX();
                    downy = event.getY();

                    Log.d("State","Show X" + Float.toString(downx));
                    Log.d("State","Show Y" + Float.toString(downy));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Make sure that you setup `OnTouchListener` for your view which drawed dots, not an other component.

Comment: Are you basing the coordinate range on when you click down? Because if you move your finger after clicking down, this code will log the coordinate when you pick your finger up.

Comment: No, I'm using `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`